# Why the equation can be equal to $(1-p)^k$?

Tags: probability-distributions

I was studying for geometric random variable, and I saw that

$$P(X>k)\sum_{i\ge k+1}p(1-p)^{i-1}$  =$(1-p)^k$$

I don't understand why it can be equal to $(1-p)^k$?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's denote $1 - p$ by $q$ for a moment, assume $0 < q < 1$.

First, notice that
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i = k + 1}^\infty q^{i - 1} \\
= & q^k + q^{k + 1} + \cdots \quad \text{collecting the common term } q^k\\
= & q^k(1 + q + q^2 + \cdots) \\ 
= & q^k \frac{1}{1 - q} \\
= & \frac{q^k}{p}
\end{align}
where we used the celebrated geometric series summation formula:
$$\boxed{1 + q + q^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - q}, \quad |q| < 1.}$$
Therefore the original summation becomes
$$p \sum_{i = k + 1}^\infty q^{i - 1} = p \frac{q^k}{p} = q^k = (1 - p)^k.$$

If $p = 1$, the equality is trivial to verify (the equality does not hold for $p = 0$ though).

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \sum_{i\ge k+1}p(1-p)^{i-1} = \sum_{i+k+1\ge k+1}p(1-p)^{i+k}=\sum_{i\ge 0}p(1-p)^{i+k} = p(1-p)^{k}\sum_{i\ge 0}(1-p)^i$

And this is equal to $\displaystyle p(1-p)^k \times \frac{1}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^k$.